# How to write xcopy command to copy only certain DLLs from project folder to bin folder

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I'm currently working in VS 2015. I have a specific unmanaged DLL that needs to be copied to my bin folder after my build operation manually.

How can I write an xcopy command to copy only that specific DLL on successful build in VS? I have figured out where it needs to be written, but not sure how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to write xcopy command to copy only certain DLLs from project folder to bin folder

You can add a xcopy command in post-build-event (Properties->Build Events->Post-build-event command line) to copy those specific dll to the bin folder:

```
xcopy.exe "$(ThePathOfSpecificDll)\Specific.dll" "$(OutDir)"
```

Note:

- You can use [Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx) to specify the path.
- Do not ignore double quotation marks.